# Virtual web server on VMWare no longer works on Windows 10

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, windows-10-upgrade

I have VMWare Workstation set up with an Ubuntu LAMP server. I set up my hosts file so that I can connect to it with a special url. I set it up so I could use it as a virtual web server and test out my web applications locally.

Under Windows 7 it worked just fine: I could open Firefox and connect to it like any other web server. But since I upgraded to Windows 10, I can't connect at all.

Before, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, and it worked for a while. But then last night my computer installed a new windows update, and now it's not working again. What's worse, uninstalling and reinstalling VMWare Workstation didn't help.

I'm not sure at all how to set things up. To make matters worse, I'm on a Japanese OS, and VMWare automatically sets the menu language to Japanese. I can read Japanese OK for most things, but I have a bit trouble navigating more technical things. So I may need a bit of extra help here.

Comment: Update: I ran ifconfig on the server and found out the virtual server has a new IP address. While this is a good enough fix for a while, I'm worried that Windows, in its infinite insanity, is going to take another look at my system and say, "yeah, you don't need that. I'm gonna make it stop working" again. Is there anything I need to do to prevent this from happening again in the future?

Comment: Put the server on a fixed IP address?